# Need a mongo driver that supports replica sets and eventmachine for ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, eventmachine

I am trying to find a ruby based mongo driver to use in my project. It has to support replicasets and eventmachine. I'm aware of em-mongo, but it does not support replicasets. It looks like there is not a good option at the moment, but I wanted to see if anyone was aware of one before I explore mongo alternatives...

Comment: Have a look at [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#replica).

Comment: I believe this driver is synchronous, although my experience is with the v2 driver, not the v3 driver. I would love to be corrected if the v3 driver can be used in an asynchronous fashion.

Comment: I too have been looking for this.

Comment: @Mika, https://github.com/fl00r/em-mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a maintainer for the 10gen Ruby driver. Hang tight, we'll have support for this in the near future.

I don't believe there is anything out there (from 10gen or otherwise) that does this currently but we're actively working on a version of our driver that supports asynchronous reads and writes.

All of the official 10gen drivers are aiming to support this by mid to end of the year and the ruby driver team is already working on it. Hopefully we'll have something for you much earlier than that (likely in our 2.0 release).

Comment: Are there experimental ones available before the stable release?

Comment: There's not anything currently available, but we'll definitely have it up in our github repo as soon as an experimental version of it is available. You're always welcome to test out our bleeding-edge code there:
http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

Comment: I've [added](https://github.com/fl00r/em-mongo) support of Replica Set into em-mongo.

Comment: Almost a year has passed, and I can't find any support for this. Seems there are no 2.0 release, but work has begun on 3.0.alpha. Brandon, do you still have plans to develop support for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [my fork](https://github.com/fl00r/em-mongo) of `em-mongo` with Replica Set support.

Also I am working on gem [Monga](https://github.com/fl00r/monga) which should support some modern features of MongoDB. But it is totally not production ready right now.